# Asterisk FastAGI sending command at the same time

Tags: asterisk, fastagi

I was using Asterisk.Net for my AGI and my asterisk server can accept a command which convert the voice to text (http://zaf.github.io/asterisk-speech-recog/). Now, I want to perform two commands at the same time which is the wait for digit and the voice to text so that it can accept key press and voice for authentication. How can I achieve this or it is possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

For now only way is create record application with dtmf collect. Need c/c++ experience.